# Removing duplicate features based on a condition on another attribute column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, select, remove

I want to remove duplicate features (from a polygons shapefile) based on a condition on another attribute column in QGIS.
For example, if I have the following attribute table of a polygon shapefile:

```
Column_A  | Column_B

1         a

2         a

1         b

2         b
```

I want to keep only one feature for each group of duplicates (or triplicates, etc) of column B, by keeping the feature corresponding to the smallest column A value for each duplicate group.

The result would be:

```
Column_A  | Column_B

1         a

1         b
```

Answer (score 5):

### Variant 1: select features to keep

Use `Select by expression` with this expression (screenshot 1):

```
column_a = minimum (column_a, group_by:=column_b)
```

Then export/save only the selected features and you're done. You get a new layer, the original data remains unchanged. All attributes for the minimum value of column A are retained (your request in a comment to the solution by @Pigreco - see screenshot 2)

Or: You could also `Invert selection` (click the icon, see screenshot 1) and delete the duplicates. All attributes for the minimum value of column A are retained (your request in a comment to the solution by @Pigreco - see screenshot 2).

---

### Variant 2: select features to delete

An even faster way (no need to invert selection): directly select the duplicates you want to delete with one of these modifications of the expression. Then delete the selected features. No new layer is created, the initial data is changed, duplicates are irrevocably deleted:

- replace `=` by `<>`:

  `column_a <> minimum (column_a, group_by:=column_b)`
- replace `=` by `!=`:

  `column_a = minimum (column_a, group_by:=column_b)` - tribute to @pigreco
- add `not` in front of the expression (screenshot 2):

  `not column_a = minimum (column_a, group_by:=column_b)`

*screenshot 1:*
[image]

*screenshot 2, including column_c that is retained - selected lines (blue) can be deleted, red ones will be kept:*
[image]

Comment: nice solution +1

Comment: should work using `!=`, i.e. the expression `column_a != minimum (column_a, group_by: = column_b)`

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same as the variant with `<>` instead of `=` - or using a `NOT` in front of the expression with `=` - will add these two additions to the solution.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed in my dataset, there might be several features presenting the same minimum value of column A among a given group of features from the same value in column B. And in this case, your solution will keep all features with the same minimum value. So maybe an addition constraint should be added, like retaining arbitrarily the FIRST minimum value of column A for each group of column B. Would you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I think so, opening a new question would be better. You can link to this question, if needed.

Comment: The solution by JGH is perfectly answering this new constraint of multiple minimum value of column A. So this JGH solution is OK for me.

Comment: OK, so then don't forget to accept JGH's answer: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

The output is a dynamic layer, which you can choose to export if you want to persist the results.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query

```sql
select min(column_a),column_b, column_c, *
from  a
group by a.column_B
```

You can choose to list the columns to be returned, or to use `min(column_a), *` to get them all.

It will return 1 row by `columnB` value. Since we are asking for the smallest `columnA`, the other field values will be for the row containing the smallest `columnA`

[image]

Comment: I tried your virtual layer solution as well. It returns the **first** column_A value for each duplicate group, whereas the OP asked for the **smallest** column A value for each duplicate group. See this case, once with my `not` selection and with your virtual layer query: if the the first one is not the smallest value, the virtual layer does not return the correct result - see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4VZv.png

Comment: @Babel Thanks! You are right I used the wrong query...  this updated version works :-)

Comment: This solution is perfectly answering the problem with the additional advantage that it will keep only one feature when there are several same minimum values of column A for a given group of column B. This additional constraint was not mentioned in the problem as I formulated it but I encountered it in my dataset. Many thanks !

Comment: Also this JGH solution works much faster than the one of BABEL that was taking a long time on my dataset (5000 features).

Answer (score 2):

From Processing Tools, search for `aggregate` algorithm:

[image]

1. select the layer of interest;
2. select the field to aggregate for duplicates;
3. select minimum value;
4. select first value

**EDIT**:

in case there was a third column `Column_C` (see message below)

[image]

the `Column_C` is calculated by expression:(>= QGIS 3.18)

```
with_variable(
    'cucu',
    array_agg( "Column_A" , "Column_B" ),
array_agg( "Column_C" , "Column_B" )[array_find(@cucu,array_min(@cucu))])
```

example data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pigreco/0ad8205396093557dad8b2d3864a6ddf/raw/039187175547c62d206b200ba15879eb3714b22f/duplicate.csv

Comment: This is a nice solution perfectly answering my request. However I forgot to mention that  I also have a column c which is text and may contain different info for each feature (for each line). The value of column c that has to be retained is the one corresponding to the feature presenting the minimum value of column A for a given group of duplicate. And I think the "aggregate" function won't be able to do so? What do you think?

Comment: but so the question is completely different, maybe it is better that I change it.
tomorrow I'll study it.

Comment: @DenisAntoine see my solution. All attributes for the minimum value of column A are automatically retained, so  column_c will be kept.

Answer (score 2):

1. Order by expression with the expression `"Field_A"||"Field_B"`

> This algorithm sorts a vector layer according to an expression. Be
> careful, it might not work as expected with some providers, the order
> might not be kept every time.

2. Delete duplicates by attribute:

> Removes duplicate rows by a field value (or multiple field values).
> **The first matching row will be retained**, and duplicates will be
> discarded. Optionally, these duplicate records can be saved to a
> separate output for analysis.